# Multiprocessing hangs up while executing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

I have a large DataFrame of minute-by-minute time series records spannings several years. I have a complex calculation I need to make for each minute, so I'm using parallel processing to speed this up. I create a separate task for each calendar day to do this.

```
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
set_start_method('spawn')
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
from lib.targetcalculations import calculate_target

# get list of unique dates in df
date_range = df.reset_index().datetime.map(labda t: t.date()).unique()

# execute processes - one task for each day
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_processes = 8
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(n_processes)
    results = p.map(calculate_target, [df.loc[str(p)] for p in date_range])
    new_df = pd.concat(results)
```

```
# lib.targetcalculations
def calculate_target(df):
    # runs calculations and returns a one-column DataFrame 
    # for simplicity this just returns a dummy
    return pd.DataFrame(data = df['column1'], index=df.index)
```

When I run my code for a smaller slice of the DataFrame, for example, one or two years, the code executes successfully in about 50 seconds per year of data. I see all cores being utilized, and I'm pleased with the result. However, when I attempt to run it for the whole DataFrame, which spans four years, it hangs up. I do see all cores being utilized at first, but eventually I see that usage fall off despite the code block not completing. I don't see my memory usage going out of control either.

I think it's important to note that I can successfully run this for each year individually, meaning the worker function is not throwing any errors anywhere in the data. Also, I am running the parallelization in jupyter, but my `targetcalculations` is a .py file.

I found an article suggesting it had something to do with "forking" in multiprocessing, so I added the `set_start_metod('spawn')` line. Same result when trying to run over several years.

Comment: Maybe it runs for each year separately without error but does that test every span? Maybe there's a data problem when run from years 1.5 to 2.5.

Comment: @Woodford since I break up the tasks by individual calendar days, I'm not sure how that could happen. But thanks for the suggestion; let me think about it